Why onmessage never triggers in my BroadcastChannel?
I'm trying to use BroadcastChannel API but it seems that onmessage event is never triggered (or its handler is not working correctly).
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('foobar')

if (channel) {
  channel.onmessage = onMessage
}

export async function onMessage(event: MessageEvent) {
  alert('onMessage') // never triggers
}

export function post(message: Message) {
  alert('post') // works until this point
  channel?.postMessage(message)
}

In other file:
import * as BroadcastChannel from '@/utils/broadcastChannel/core'

BroadcastChannel.post('test')

Am I doing something incorrectly? Am I missing something?
Edit: I misunderstood the purpose of BroadcastChannel. It will send the message only from one opened tab/window to another. If I have the app opened on one tab only it doesn't work at all, as this sent message is simply not designed to be picked up on the same tab.

The method is postMessage

@DanielA.White ? I don't understand, I'm using postMessage in my post function.

Since there's conditional chaining on channel, have you checked it actually exists at the point this is called?
